# Custom exception in C++ for invalid input to a function

Tags: c++, c++11, error-handling

I would like to write a custom Error class in C++. I am mostly used to Java (not used them a lot) so I would like to check here if my thought process on how to do this in C++ is correct.

Currently I got the following code:

```
class InvalidInput : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    InvalidInput(const char* msg) : std::runtime_error(msg) {

    }
};
```

I plan on using the cutsom error in a function as so:

```
myFunc(int x) {
    if (valueIsInvalid(x)) {
        throw InvalidInput ("invalid input");
    }
}
```

Before implementing it I would like to know if I am on the right track on how this should be done in C++ (as well as best practice). If there is a better way feel free to tell me as well.

Comment: Unlike Java, exceptions should be used sparingly in C++. Throwing an exception in C++ is expensive, and should be used only for truly exceptional cases. For input validation en exception should typically only be thrown if the program can't really continue anymore.

Comment: Regarding the comment by @Evg, you could also use `struct` instead of `class`, as then members will be `public` by default.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would consider human input as so slow (compared to speed of computations) that I wouldn't be afraid about performance impact too much (in this case).

Comment: Note that C++ has [`std::invalid_argument`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument) exception.

Comment: @Evg thank you. I added the public keyword in case anyone finds this post in the future.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica that error class looks like it is meant for input which causes problems with logic. Wrong input in this case will not result in a logic error but will not abide to business rules.

Comment: Instead, of `std::runtime_error`, you may consider to derive from [`std::ios::failure`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure). I believe this is thrown as well for errors in formatting input (if exceptions are enabled for the stream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your solution as below.

> create custome exception

```
class InvalidInput : public std::exception{

   public:
       InvalidInput(std::string msg):errorMsg_(msg){}   

   virtual const char* what() const throw()
   {
       return errorMsg_;
   }

   private:
       std::string errorMsg_;
};
```

> use of that custome excetion

```
myFunc(int x) {
    if (valueIsInvalid(x)) {
         throw InvalidInput ("invlaid input");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can complete your answer by mentioning that it is possible to `const char* what() override`